# Natural log of 2 from geometric series

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

We have that the Taylor series expansion of the natural logarithm function is $$\text{log}(x) = \sum_{n \geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}(x - 1)^n$$ and that its interval of convergence is $(0, 2]$, which is not hard to establish using e.g. the Ratio test (plus independent boundary analysis). However, I am aware of an alternative derivation of the Taylor series of log$(x)$ using geometric series, but I am uncertain of the behavior at the boundary. Specifically, using the fact that $\sum_{n \geq 0}r^n = \frac{1}{1 - r}$ for $|r| < 1$, we have that $$\frac{d}{dx}\text{log}(x) = \frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{1 - (1 - x)} =^* \sum_{n \geq 0}(1 - x)^n$$ and so integrating should give us the Taylor series for log as already given. However, regarding the "$=^*$", we only have equality when $|1 - x| < 1$, i.e. when $x \in (0, 2)$. This means that this derivation does not justify why $x = 2$ is in the interval of convergence. How are we supposed to be able to infer the fact that the series also converges at $x = 2$ based off this derivation? Does this simply mean that this derivation is not rigorous/complete, and we should instead use alternative methods to establish that the given series really is the Taylor series of log$(x)$?

Comment: The interval of convergence is $(0,2]$; the radius of convergence is $1$.

Comment: Oops, my mistake. Thanks for pointing it out - it's fixed now.

Comment: Generally speaking, convergence on the boundary cannot be resolved via kinds of tests which give absolute convergence in the interior of the interval of convergence.  In this case, with $x=0$, the resulting series is the Harmonic Series (which diverges---this is a fairly standard result), and with $x=2$, the resulting series is the Alternating Harmonic Series (which converges by the alternating series test).

Comment: That being said, you seem to claim (in your first sentence) that you can establish convergence at $x=2$ using the ratio test.  I do not believe that this is correct.

Comment: I guess I am being slightly loose with my justification- what I really mean is "Ratio test plus independent boundary analysis".

Comment: I understand that these series do diverge (resp. converge) at $x = 0$ ($x = 2$) it is just that I am unsure why there is this seeming inconsistency: on the one hand we can independently verify that the series converges at $x = 2$, but on the other it seems that it shouldn't based on the formula/convergence criteria for geometric series. The geometric series derivation suggests that the series should diverge at $x = 2$, yet we can see at the end that it does not.

Comment: Under what conditions are you "permitted" to bring an integral or derivative into a sum?  You might want to check those hypotheses carefully.  The geometric series converges (absolutely) on an open interval; the series obtained by integrating that series converges (*a priori*) on that same open interval.  The behaviour on the boundary is not given by any particular theorem that I am aware of.

Comment: Ok I see. So we can say that log(x) is the integral of the sum, but as soon as we want to distribute the integral to each summand, we can only do so assuming absolute convergence of the series. And we do not have that for $\sum_{n \geq 0}(1 - x)^n$ at $x = 2$, meaning it bears no relationship to the integrated series $\sum_{n \geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}(x - 1)^n$ outside that interval of (absolute) convergence, namely at $x = 2$. Is that your point? In any case, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The questions are:

- *"How are we supposed to be able to infer the fact that the series also converges at $x=2$ based off this derivation?"* We can't, as you observe.
- *"Does this simply mean that this derivation is not rigorous/complete, and we should instead use alternative methods to establish that the given series really is the Taylor series of $\log x$?"* The derivation is not complete in this detail, but it's certainly rigorous: it correctly proves the implication "if $|x-1|<1$ then the Taylor series converges to $\log x$", without making a claim for other values of $x$.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. And as was pointed out in the comments, the reason that the analysis is not complete (in the sense of neglecting the case of $x = 2$) is that we can only integrate when the series converges absolutely, which is not the case for the above geometric series at $x = 2$. This explains why the geometric series diverges at $x = 2$ while the integrated series (corresponding to log(x)) converges at $x = 2$.